# Kafka connector insert transform string into property

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using [Kafa connect solr](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-solr) and I'm trying to find a way to change the solr url based on the passed in topic, I've been looking at Kafka [connect_transforms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms) to try and achieve this. My connect properties file looks like this -

```
topics.regex=foo.*.bar
solr.url=http://127.0.0.1:8910/solr/RemoveString$Value
transforms=RemoveString
transforms.RemoveString.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.RemoveString.regex=(^foo.)(\w*\d+)(.*)
transforms.RemoveString.replacement=$2
```

How can i use the RemoveString value in the solr.url property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transforms` really only alter the Kafka Record itself, not external properties such as the clients that the Connect tasks may use

Specifically, look at the [source code](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-solr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jcustenborder/kafka/connect/solr/HttpSolrSinkTask.java#L44), and you'll see that it uses topic names to map to individual clients, but all at the same url

Comment: Understood, it does seem though that the collection can be passed in using transforms, so the url would remain as solr.url=http://127.0.0.1:8910/solr/ and then transforms would be used to pass in the collection. From what I can tell the syntax of the transform I have above looks correct I'm confused though on how that would actually be passed in.

Comment: I don't specifically know how `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.UpdateRequest` works, but I dont see anywhere in the code where the topic name is actually sent through the client; it's only used for the map lookup and all clients use the same URL

Comment: I was actually able to get this working by using the zookeeper approach within the connector and using the regex transform to specify my collection.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the SolrCloud code was any different than SolrHttp

Comment: I was surprised myself but it does indeed pass the topic in as the collection https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-solr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jcustenborder/kafka/connect/solr/CloudSolrSinkTask.java
I have a working example but the regex I'm using isn't as dynamic as I would like it to be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836964/kafka-transforms-ignoring-regex