# Kafka transforms ignoring regex

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to use kafka [transforms.RemoveString](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html) to modify the name of my topic before passing it into my connector. My topic name looks like this

```
foo.bar_1.baz
```

I want to extract **bar_1** and pass that in as the topic name. From what I can tell my [regex is correct](https://regexr.com/640ra) but the kafka transform doesn't seem to like it -

```
transforms=ReplaceField,RenameField,RemoveString
transforms.RemoveString.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.RemoveString.regex=(\w*.)(\w*\d+)(.*)
transforms.RemoveString.replacement=$2
```

I can tell the RemoveString is being used as when I change the regex to the following I get my desired results but this is rather restrictive for my use case -

```
transforms.RemoveString.regex=(foo.)(.*)(.baz)
transforms.RemoveString.replacement=$2
```

Is there some sort of limitation to the regex usage within Kafka transforms?

Comment: Maybe you have missed `transforms=RemoveString`

Comment: it's included I'll add it above.

Comment: I would use `(\w*)\.(\w+)\.(.*)` since `\w` includes digits already

Comment: Same results with `(\w*)\.(\w+)\.(.*)` its passing the full topic name through still, it seems like it doesn't like the use of `\w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, backslashes had to be escaped, with my improved regex it now looks like this -

```
(\\w*)\\.(\\w+)\\.(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in RegexRouter, You missed the `R`

```
transforms=ReplaceField,RenameField,RemoveString
transforms.RemoveString.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.RemoveString.regex=(\w*.)(\w*\d+)(.*)
transforms.RemoveString.replacement=$2
```

Comment: Apologies copy/paste error on my behalf, my actual file has it listed correctly.

Comment: Are you getting some errors? did you see in logs?

Comment: No errors in logs but i did revisit them there and I've noticed the issue, it seems that it was removing the backslashes when the properties were loaded.